# How to deal with a proprietary Python package name conflicting with a public one?

Tags: python, debian, package, naming

### Background

The group I work with has been using and developing a Python package, which for the purposes of this question I'll call `foobuilder`. We serve updates for Linux systems using private RPM and Deb repositories we provide for our users.

Recently, a public package was added to PyPi with the same name. It also got packaged on the public Debian repository, among other places. Since we don't publicly advertise our package, it's understandable that a package with the same name has popped up.

### Concerns

This looks like a big problem for `foobuilder` because somewhere down the line, a user might try to install our `foobuilder` while the public `foobuilder` package is installed on the same system.

Besides the obvious problem in Python, I would guess that adding our repository to a Debian package manager program could also cause some issues, though I haven't played around with this situation yet.

### Problem

Since we've been using the proprietary `foobuilder` for years, there is a ton of code in existence which wants to `import foobuilder` and expects to get our package, so I don't think it's feasible to change the name.

### My thoughts on possible solutions

#### Python

I've considered changing the name of the package to `my_foobuilder`, and having it include a meta-package called `foobuilder` which consists only of an `__init__.py` that imports everything from `my_foobuilder`. I could instruct new users to import `my_foobuilder` directly. Then I could begin to deprecate the `foobuilder` name. In the end this would result in the same amount of work as if I changed `foobuilder` to `my_foobuilder` now, since everyone needs to be served updates and the `foobuilder` name can't be in deprecation purgatory forever.

#### Debian

The Debian problem shouldn't be too hard to solve; I can change the debian package name to `my_foobuilder` but have it still install the same (conflicting) Python package. I could then set the `my_foobuilder` package to `Conflict` with `foobuilder`. It might require users to fiddle around with their package manager to get things back on track during the transition but I don't think that's a big deal. Still, this prevents users from using the public `foobuilder` package at the same time.

### Question

Is there an easier or better way to treat this situation than what I've considered above? Are there any problems with the solutions I'm considering? How would you deal with this?

Comment: Not a technical solution, but have you considered approaching the author of the public package with the same name and politely asking if they could use another name. They're within their rights to refuse, of course, but they might be as keen to avoid the conflict as you are, and if it's a new package, it's easier to change.

Comment: I think your suggested approach is exactly what I would do. I would also add a metapackage that allows the conflicting package to be imported by another name (and make sure your package is preferentially imported over the public package)

Answer (score 3):

I'd **email** the new foobuilder package author to discuss the problem. Obviously one of you needs to *change package name*; due to proprietary nature of your program is may be undesirable to change its name... Asking this question to the new package author may come up with some new solutions.

There really is no sane way to have Python handle this in a way so 'import foobuilder' can mean 2 things.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a kludge would be fine here as long as the kludge is controlled. If I were in your situation, I would create a file with some other identifier to your package such as `so.py` and have the contents be

```
import relative_pathname/foobuilder as my_foobuilder
```

Then the package can be referenced as so.my_foobuilder unambiguously without requiring either team to change their product name. It is not a great solution, since all internals would need to be shifted, but it should resolve the conflict without requiring more of a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks?

```
$ echo "print 'foo'" > foo.py
$ ln -s foo.py bar.py
$ python -c "import foo; import bar"
foo
foo
```

Very simple, albeit kind of hackish :)

Comment: hmm, although this won't solve the "import foobuilder" problem, for which you'd likely have to either a) actually rename the public package, or b) set PYTHONPATH/sys.path to give your package priority.